# Fourier transform of a piecewise

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform

How should I go about seeking the Fourier transform for the piecewise function:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 ,&|x|>a \\ 
1 ,&|x|<a 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is this the correct attempt?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-a}^{0}1e^{i\omega x}.dx+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{a}0e^{i \omega x}.dx$$?

Comment: Yes, but there is no point in splitting the integral into two parts, also note the function is even, so it simplifies a little. You should end up with some version of $\operatorname{sinc}$.

Comment: Integration is with respect to x and not $\omega$ and the integrand should be other way ie 1 for $0$ to $a$

Comment: There is a tugging feeling in me that is unconvinced that this is the correct bound due to the fact that all values of "a" could lie on the positive or negative domain. The bound in my attempt seems to imply that otherwise.

Comment: @Loophole Could you explain why the integrand should be f(x)=1 for bounds between 0 and a?

Comment: No. Here there are 3 ranges : $(- \infty , -a), (-a, a), (a, \infty)$ in which f(x) is 1 in the second domain and 0 in the rest.

Comment: I'm getting conflicting answers. This isn't good..

Comment: @L16H7 does this involves the idea around the Dirac Delta 'function'?

Comment: No, you can solve it without knowledge of dirac delta function. Delta function has value of 1 at only one point while in your question it is 1 in the range of (-a, a).

Comment: @L16H7 However, why does the piecewise says 0 for |x| >a ?

Comment: It can say anything. 0 just makes the problem simpler.

Comment: If a = 0, then the function would be a delta function having value 1 at x = 0 only and 0 elsewhere. The given function is called rectangular function, I think. Look at its graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in questions is $1$ on $[-a,a]$ and $0$ elsewhere. So the Fourier transform of this function is
$$
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a}^{a}e^{-isx}dx = \left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-isx}}{-is}\right|_{x=-a}^{x=a}
       = \frac{e^{isa}-e^{-isa}}{\sqrt{2\pi}is}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(sa)}{s}
$$
This is the "sinc" function, and you'll want to become familiar with this functon.